# SQL Server Database Project (SSDP) update fails when strings contain dollar sign $

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-update, database-schema

We have a scenario where we have some scripts that auto-populate certain database tables during database migration/updates.

One of these tables has a column that typically stores jQuery javascript.  So, a column might look like this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SomeTable] ([LaunchJs])
VALUES (N'$(.client).init();')
```

The problem we're having is that the schema update fails, because the updater thinks that the dollar sign is for a server variable even though it is contained within an NVARCHAR string.

Specs:

- SSDP 2012 (more than likely applies to al versions)
- VS 2013
- .NET 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround we found is to build the string using concatenation, eg:

```
--NCHAR(36): dollar sign
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SomeTable] ([LaunchJs])
VALUES (NCHAR(36) + N'(.client).init();')
```